# excel: import text from text file, onto next available row on spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, text, import

I am using the following VBA code to import text from my text file into columns in excel, it's working great apart from the fact it is always inserting my text on row 1 and overwitting whatever text was previously in that row. I need a way for the code to insert the text onto the next available row on my spreadsheet?

Here's my code:

```
    Sub ImportFile()
    Close #1
    Open "Y:\Incident Logs\INSC89JH.txt" For Input As #1
    A = 1
     Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            Cells(A) = TextLine
            A = A + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing 
`Cells(A) = TextLine`

To 
`Range("A" & A).Value = TextLine`

This should work putting the text file which has new lines in, into a new row each loop

EDIT. Ignore the top part of my answer. Left it in if anyone finds it usefull.

You will need to get a check to see what range was used.

Try this

```
Sub ImportFile()

    Dim rowCount As Long

    rowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    If Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then rowCount = 1


    Close #1
    Open "Y:\Incident Logs\INSC89JH.txt" For Input As #1
    A = 1
     Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            Cells(rowCount, A) = TextLine
            A = A + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: no this doesn't work, it just causes all my text to be imported in one column in multiple rows, instead it should import the text into different columns on one row and each time I run a new text import it should insert it onto the next available row

Comment: Oh I see. Misunderstood the question. I will update my answer

Comment: my text file structure is just like this: Line 1 = Reference, Line 2 = Hello, Line 3 = Cars

Comment: ok it's now importing the text correctly, each new line in my text file is inserted into another column on one row which is what I needed, however when I try to import the text file again, it is not being inserted onto the next available row, in fact nothing gets imported at all the second time?

Comment: sorry my mistake It was inserting into a new row  just down the bottom of the spreadseet because I didn't delete the rows from before when I was testing it. its working now thansk

Answer (score 0):

Change

`Cells(A) = TextLine`

to

`Cells(A, 1) = TextLine`

where the 1 in `Cells(A, 1)`stands for the number of the column (in this case column A) you want to insert the text to. So if you want it in column C, change it to `Cells(A, 3)`.

Comment: That would either need to be manually put in each time to update the columnNo or automattically like my answer

Comment: well I got rid of that to avoid confusion. You didn't need to update it manually anyways